# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when converting gensim to tensorboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, gensim

I am converting a `gensim` w2v file to a `Tensorboard` tsv file with this code:

```
with open(outfiletsv, 'w+b') as file_vector:
    with open(outfiletsvmeta, 'w+b') as file_metadata:
        for word in model.index2word:
            file_metadata.write(gensim.utils.to_utf8(word) + gensim.utils.to_utf8('\n'))
            vector_row = '\t'.join(str(x) for x in model[word])
            file_vector.write(vector_row + '\n')
```

It results in this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\_repos\special\word2vec2tensor.py in <module>()
     79 
     80     logger.info("running %s", ' '.join(sys.argv))
---> 81     word2vec2tensor(args.input, args.output, args.binary)
     82     logger.info("finished running %s", os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))

~\_repos\special\word2vec2tensor.py in word2vec2tensor(word2vec_model_path, tensor_filename, binary)
     61                 file_metadata.write(gensim.utils.to_utf8(word) + gensim.utils.to_utf8('\n'))
     62                 vector_row = '\t'.join(str(x) for x in model[word])
---> 63                 file_vector.write(vector_row + '\n')
     64 
     65     logger.info("2D tensor file saved to %s", outfiletsv)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I added `b` to the original `w+` in the open file pieces to counteract the opposite issue (`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`).

I tried adding `vector_row = vector_row.encode('UTF-8'), but this did not work.

How do I remedy this `TypeError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just convert your string back to bytes:

```
file_vector.write(vector_row.encode() + b'\n')
```

However your code already reads the file as bytes and then you explicitly convert to str with this (i guess): `'\t'.join(str(x) for x in model[word])`

So you might want to clean up and use bytes everywhere instead of going back and forth :)